# @font-face not working on Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, css, font-face

I use this code to implement a personalized font:

CSS

```
     @font-face{
    font-family:'playtime';
    src: url('../fonts/font-1.otf') format('opentype');
    }
    p.playtime-font {

    font-family: 'playtime', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="texto-horario">
        <p class="playtime-font">Horario</p>
    </div>
```

But it does not work, I've tried it on Chrome and Safari and nothing...
I don't know what I am doing wrong please anyone can help me?

Comment: Does it work on any other browsers? Or do you just mean the only ones you've tried are Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Also, please add the HTML of an element you are trying to apply the font to, it may be a small typo type issue

Comment: @Parker I've only tried on Chrome and Safari because I think those are the most used browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the single quotes:

```
 @font-face{
    font-family: playtime;
    src: url('../fonts/font-1.otf') format('opentype');
    }
    p.playtime-font {
    font-family: playtime;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

If this doesn't work, is your console saying anything?

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly without using the quotes :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.